# How to make multiple line sliders in circular form?

Tags: angular, slider, uislider, designer, round-slider

I am unable to find any solution to make the **multiple line sliders** in **circular** form.
I have tried to make it with the help of roundSlider
https://roundsliderui.com/demos.html
but unable to achieve it. 
Please suggest which slider, I need to use for it?
[image: round slider]

It needs to look like this, but each dash will be a different slider?

Comment: what do you want in the end?

Comment: Suggestions, how can I achieve this type of slider?

Comment: puff, it's not easy. first you need know how draw a circular gauge by css, after control the mouse down and mouse up. I made sometime ago some similar. You can check in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vh2uu1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html if you want at first step. If I get time to explain I put as answer

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by the [**roundSlider**](https://roundsliderui.com/) plugin itself. In the 1.4.0 version, the SVG mode was released, by using that you can achieve similar appearance.

---

Check the below demo:

## [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/ag1vk9od/)

[image: multiple arc sliders in circular form]

Comment: How can we merge these labels into a single centered label?

Comment: you can create any element as your custom tooltip and update that value from the `valueChange` event. Check the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/wg7bqvL1/